# trying to Implement a stack of structs

Tags: c, struct, stack

My assignment says :

Write a program to perform following stack operations : Create a stack with item code and quantity

```
Itemcode    Quantity
    111     450
    112     0
    113     487
    114     101
    115     500
    116     0
    117     359
```

and then Delete the items having quantity zero and update the stack.

My code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define LEN 7
struct item { int* num ; int* q; }

int main(void){
    int length = LEN,i,j;
    struct item data[LEN];

    // read input data into struct
    for(i=0 ; i < LEN ; i++){
        printf(" %d . enter item-code : ",i);
        scanf("%d",data[i].num);
        printf(" %d . enter quantity : ",i);
        scanf("%d",data[i].num);
    }

    // Delete the items having quantity zero and update the stack
    for(i=0 ; i < length ; i++) if(*data[i].q == 0){
        for(j=i+1;j<length;j++) 
            data[j-1] = data[j]; // update by overwriting
        data[j] = NULL;
        length--;
    }

    // display stack
    for(i=0 ; i < length && data[i]!= NULL; i++){
        printf(" %d > item : %d , quantity : %d\n",i,*data[i].num,*data[i].q);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its the 1st time i'm working with structs in C . The errors i get are :

```
StructStack.c:5: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
StructStack.c: In function 'main':                                                                   
StructStack.c:21: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct item' from type 'void *'  
StructStack.c:26: error: invalid operands to binary != (have 'struct item' and 'void *')             
StructStack.c:30: error: incompatible types when returning type 'int' but 'struct item' was expected
```

Any help would be great.

regards
Somjit.

Comment: add ; after the sruct{};

Answer (score 1):

My best guess: the missing semicolon after the struct.

When programming on C, that kind of things are the first you have to take a look at.

Answer (score 1):

Missing semicolon after the struct, but also the set/comparison to NULL is done on the struct instead of the members. Instead of:

`data[j] = NULL;`

you might instead use:

`data[j].num = NULL;
 data[j].q = NULL;`

Comment: ...and also `for(i=0 ; i < length && data[i]!= NULL; i++)` becomes `for(i=0 ; i < length && data[i].num != NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few syntax errors in your code.

For the struct definition, aside from the no semi-colon at the end, why are you using pointers?

`struct item { int* num ; int* q; }` becomes
`struct item { int num; int q; };`

`scanf` takes address of the variable, so `scanf("%d",data[i].num)` becomes
`scanf("%d", &data[i].num)`

You don't need `data[j] = NULL` either. You have `length` to keep track.

You also don't need any `*` in front of your `data` variable because you're not dealing with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It's C. You can't do:

```
int a = <something>, another_variable;
```

You have to put the declaration and assignment into different lines. So,

```
int a, another_variable;
a = <something>;
```

Also, as the others mentioned, the ";" after the struct declaration, and the & before each variable in the scanf()

Comment: Your claim _You can't do: `int a = <something>, another_variable;`_ is wrong.